# Comparing a particular part of a string with another string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
int main()
{
char *a = "i am mad";
string str(a);
cout<<str.rfind("mad");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

So I am trying to compare a particular part of a string.Let's say the string contains `mad` then I would perform some operation and if not I will perform some other operation. My source string is present in const char format only.
I am able to find where the sub-string is i.e. `mad` but I can't use it to compare with something.

This is how I found the location of the substring but I don't know how to compare.
what should I change?
i know that  `mad` starts from 5th location but then how do I compare .?

Comment: I am quite new to programming. Can you tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a comparison on the result of `rfind()`.

```
int main()
{
    const char *a = "i am mad";
    string str(a);

    if (str.rfind("mad") == string::npos) // string::npos means not found, according to the docs
    {
        cout << "All is well" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Uh oh, somebody's mad!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are able to find the starting index of a mad then just create a substr from it . 
str2 = str.substr (starting index of 'mad', length of 'mad')

then you can use str2 to compare with other

Answer (score 0):

you can compare the return index with string::npos

```
int ret = str.rfind("mad", str.length());
if (ret != string::npos)
{
    // mad found in str
}
else
{
    // mad not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be also interested in regular expressions. They'd allow you to do that and much more...
Look e.g. here for starters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression (if you don't know what regex is) and here for C++ STL regex implementation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/